# How to group new calculations using summarise?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I would like to group the data by column `y`. I have additional calculations for differences that I need to sum up for each value y. 
Is the function `summarise` is correct for this type of calculation?

```
x <- sample(c(0:5),20, replace = T)
y <- rep(c("A", "B","C","D"), each = 5)
df <- data.frame(y, x)

inds <- c(0, diff(df$x))
inds <- -inds * (inds < 0)

df %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarise(inds <- c(0, diff(df$x)), 
            inds <- -inds * (inds < 0))

> inds
[1] 0 2 0 0 5 0 0 1 2
> cbind(df, inds)
  y x inds
1 A 3    0
2 A 1    2
3 A 5    0
4 B 5    0
5 B 0    5
6 B 1    0
7 C 3    0
8 C 2    1
9 C 0    2

Desired outcome:
y x new_variable
1 A 2    
2 B 5    
3 C 3
```

Actually I get error:

> Error: Column inds <- c(0, diff(df$x)) must be length 1 (a summary value), not 9.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(inds = c(0, diff(x)), 
         inds = -inds * (inds < 0)) %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(inds))

#   y       sum
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 A         2
#2 B         5
#3 C         3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), x = c(3L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` plus no need for `$` inside `%>%` and use `set.seed` with `sample` to ensure reproducibility.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(y) %>% 
    summarise(inds = sum(-c(0, diff(x)) * (c(0, diff(x)) < 0)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  y      inds
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         2
2 B         5
3 C         3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can first use `mutate` to create the `inds` column and `summarise` afterwards:

```
df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(inds = x - dplyr::lag(x, default = x[1])) %>%
  summarise(inds_new = sum(-inds[inds < 0]))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  y     inds_new
  <fct>    <int>
1 A            5
2 B            2
3 C            3
4 D            3
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could do this in base R.

```
aggregate(. ~ y, transform(DF, ind=-c(0, diff(DF$x)) * (c(0, diff(DF$x)) < 0)), sum)
#   y x ind
# 1 A 9   2
# 2 B 6   5
# 3 C 5   3
```

## Data

```
DF <- structure(list(y = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), x = c(3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "data.frame")
```